# Unusual DV Odds Ratio for multiple Binary Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, diagnostic

I am attempting to diagnose issues with the DV odds ratio and resulting 95% CI for the final step of my logistic regression. As you can see in the below image, when the "Continuous F" variable is added to the regression, the odds ratio changes drastically for the DV (i.e., "Intercept" in output table). Both categories of the binary outcome are well represented (Cat 0: n=437, Cat 1: n=236)

[image: Binary Logistic Regression Output]

I probed several diagnostic plots:

[image: AUC]

[image: Residuals]

[image: Continuous IV to logit relationships]

[image: Cooks Distance]

[image: Standardized Residuals]

All of this seems to fall into line. There are no multivariate outliers (>3 sds). I looked at VIF and none of the predictors had a value >2. I am not sure why the introduction of the "Continuous F" variable changes the model so drastically.

Does anyone have additional suggestions of diagnostic steps to help uncover the unusual odds ratio and CI for the final model step (OR: 183.86, 95% CI 11.16 - 3029.99)?